# DotNetNuke - Purge Log Buffer started, but hasn't ended

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have an instance of DotNetNuke where the server disk space got full while executing a task in the scheduler.  What ended up happening was that the task "Purge Log Buffer" started before the disk space got full, and never ended even after tweaking our server.  This image is the result of the ongoing issue.  As you can see, The duration of the Task keeps going up, and I'm not sure if this is an issue or not, but I would very much like to make the task stop.  [dotnetnuke Scheduler task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShznG.jpg)

Comment: Just because the task duration keeps increasing, doesn't necessarily means the process is still running.  It just means the task never got the 'completed' return.  Usually recycling the application pool will ensure any task scheduler threads are reset.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I did recycle the application pool but I wasn't sure if the process was continuing or not.  I'll mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DotNetNuclear mentioned, even if the task duration keeps increasing, it doesn't necessarily means the process is still running.  I ended up adding an endDate in the database with a comment under the ScheduleHistory table to not see that value increase.